# Function is not defined error when using ajax inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: GetLicenceUserList is not defined` in the browser console when I call the function using `$.ajax` function inside.

But the call of my function works just fine when I call it with only an `alert("example");` inside.

This are the code of both examples.

```
function GetLicenceUserList(id, actPage = 1, actualSearch = "", colOrder = 2, colDirec = "desc") {

alert(id + " - " + actPage + " - " + actualSearch + " - " + colOrder + " - " + colDirec);

/*$.ajax({
    url: "/Licences/UserLicenceList",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        userId: id,
        actPage = actPage,
        actualSearch = actualSearch,
        colOrder = colOrder,
        colDirec = colDirec
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    $("#userLicence-list-card").html(result);
    alert("ok");
}).fail(function () {
    //operaciones en caso de falla
    alert("fail");
});*/
}
```

This one works great, and the following is where the error occurs (when uncomment the ajax call):

```
function GetLicenceUserList(id, actPage = 1, actualSearch = "", colOrder = 2, colDirec = "desc") {

//alert(id + " - " + actPage + " - " + actualSearch + " - " + colOrder + " - " + colDirec);

$.ajax({
    url: "/Licences/UserLicenceList",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        userId: id,
        actPage = actPage,
        actualSearch = actualSearch,
        colOrder = colOrder,
        colDirec = colDirec
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    $("#userLicence-list-card").html(result);
    alert("ok");
}).fail(function () {
    //operaciones en caso de falla
    alert("fail");
});
}
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Jejun sorry, fixed :D

Comment: Use a tool like eslint or jshint. You've made a few (identical) typos and generated a syntax error. Object literals use `key: value` pairs, not `key = value` pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data object is not defined correctly in $ajax

You are using equals signs (=) instead of colons (:).

The data object should be like this instead:

```js
data: {
        userId: id,
        actPage: actPage,
        actualSearch: actualSearch,
        colOrder: colOrder,
        colDirec: colDirec
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! this was the problem :)